# JFrame moving when only making invisible, then visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JFrame, which I sometimes need to make invisible, then visible again. I have noticed that it moves up the screen a little whenever this happens. I even tested why this was happening by stripping all code except for the JFrame, and called setVisible(false), then true, and the same thing happened. 
Here is a minimal example, I include the OK button to represent the other things I want to get done between making the frame invisible and visible:

```
public class CopyOfPanel {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton buttn;                              //the ok button

    public CopyOfPanel(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        OKHandler ok = new OKHandler();
        buttn = new JButton("OK");
        buttn.addActionListener(ok);                    //add the listener
        frame.add(buttn);   

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
    public static void main (String[] args){
        CopyOfPanel copy = new CopyOfPanel();
    }

private class OKHandler implements ActionListener {     //for the ok button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){     
        frame.setVisible(false); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }}
}
```

Is there an easy to prevent this please?

Comment: It sounds more like the frame should be a `JDialog` using `setLocationRelativeTo(component)` before `setVisible(true)`.. BTW -`frame.setSize(600,400);` better to `pack()` whether as a frame or dialog.

Comment: i've added a minimal example which has the same issue

Comment: Here, it stays smack in the center of the screen, no matter how many times I click the button.  What OS are you on?  What is the make and version of the Java run-time?

Comment: Yes, I removed it. I realized that the second class is within the first.

Comment: @Andrew that is interesting. according to terminal i am using java version "1.7.0_65" on ubuntu 1404

Comment: BTW - are you clicking on the button using the mouse, or activating it using the keyboard?  I cannot see exactly why this would happen, but perhaps the act of clicking on the button is also moving the mouse a little each time, and the OS interprets that as 'drag the window'..

Comment: on me it's even worse, it gets white for about x milliseconds, and then getting normal ...., sometimes freezes out

Comment: @Andrew it can't be that, tried experimenting to see and it is definitely not.